# Draw a line using the mouse in the Visio DLL under .NET

Tags: c#, line, draw, visio

I'm trying to enable the drawing tools in my Visio object with C# (if you have a hint in VB it's welcome!). What I need is NOT the .DrawLine(shape, x1, y1, x2, y2) function, but changing the current mode (selection) by the drawing mode (line, rectangle or whatever shape I can select).

Any hint?

Comment: I don't even know what you're asking about. What do you mean by "changing the current mode by the drawing mode"?

Comment: I'm sorry. I though it was clear enough. In fact, in the Visio software, in the toolbar, you can find a Drawing Tools button which open a little window in which you can select Line, Square, Round, etc.

I want to launch the command that make my cursor a line drawer instead of a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why do you want to change the selected drawing tool?

If all you want to do is change the selected drawing tool you can use the [DoCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765186.aspx) method on the Application object. These two statements in VBA will change the drawing tool to the Line tool and Rectangle tool respectively:

```
Visio.Application.DoCmd visCmdDRLineTool  
Visio.Application.DoCmd visCmdDRRectTool
```

For more see [DoCmd/DOCMD Commands on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff768010.aspx).

DoCmd may not do what you expect if the current window is not a drawing window or if the application is in a modal state. You should guard against such a state and expect DoCmd to return an error and/or throw an exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much Pat, it is exactly what I was looking for! I'm sorry if my explanations wasn't clear enough, but you got it!